# ImportError: cannot import name UNAUTHORIZED_CODES

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Am using mongoengine ORM but i recently upgraded mongoengie to 0.9 which had me to downgrade my pymongo to version 2.8. Whenever i try to make a connection to the database using the code

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('dbName')
```

i get this error

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /root/Documents/Projects/BetCafe/main/tester.py   
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/root/Documents/Projects/BetCafe/main/tester.py", line 1, in <module>  
from mongoengine import *  

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>  
import fields  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 19, in <module>  
import gridfs  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gridfs/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>  
from pymongo.common import UNAUTHORIZED_CODES, validate_string    
ImportError: cannot import name UNAUTHORIZED_CODES  

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

i have tried reinstalling both pymongo and mongoengine, but neither of them works

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade pymongo? Upgrade gridfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a new version of GridFS (it has required the `UNAUTHORIZED_CODES` constant in [PyMongo since version 3.1](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-860)) with your downgraded version of Pymongo, version 2.8.

Try deleting the directories `gridfs`, `bson`, and `pymongo` from `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` then install PyMongo again.